# c++ How to Read unaligned file header into padded header struct using ifstream?

Tags: c++, struct, padding, ifstream, memory-alignment

I am currently trying to read a .tga file header using ifstream into a header struct. The problem is that the struct is being padded. Does anyone know a way around this without forces the struct to allocate unaligned?

```
struct TARGA_HEADER {
unsigned char   IDLength;
unsigned char   ColorMapType;
unsigned char   ImageType;
// 1 Bytes Padding
unsigned short  FirstEntryIndex;
unsigned short  ColorMapLength;
unsigned char   ColorMapEntrySize;
// 1 Bytes Padding
unsigned short  XOrigin;
unsigned short  YOrigin;
unsigned short  Width;
unsigned short  Height;
unsigned char   PixelDepth;
unsigned char   Descriptor;
```

};

Comment: Normally you write serialization and deserialization functions compatible with streams so you can `out << header` and `in >> header` without a lot of fuss. What have you got there? You'll need to carefully read in the right number of bytes and drop it into each property.

Comment: I use the read() method and read the whole struct in at once for performance reasons.

Comment: @tadman I use the read() method and read the whole struct in at once for performance reasons.

Comment: @Shaun280990 right and if you use compiler specific packing directives like `pragma pack` or `__attribute__((packed))` then you pay for the unaligned access on each read and write instead of just once when serializing/deserializing. I'd say, just don't pack the struct, pick apart the bytes if you absolutely need to read it just once

Comment: With a buffered stream the performance difference is less than you think, so don't stress about it unless you have a *measurable* problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for replys.